# Python | Python.exe- Entry point not found

Tags: python-3.x, system, kivy

I installed (extracted) Kivy (Kivy-1.9.0-py3.4-win32-x86.exe) on my PC (Win7 32bit). Now whenever trying to run a file using kivy-3.4.bat getting an error message within a window...

> python.exe- Entry point not found
>
> The procedure entry point inflateReset2 could not be located in the dynamic link library zlib1.dll.

Once click on the "Ok" button I see

> [Critical ] [app] unable to get a window, abort

on CMD.

I think this is a problem related to my system and Python more than Kivy. Can anyone tell me what is the problem and how to solve it?

**This is amazing!! Even in StackOverFlow no one could give me any solution!!**

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I know this post is a bit old, but maybe someone else searches this.

I got the same error. And really, I just tried to start the python script via MS Powershell instead of CMD. I just wanted to use the PS one time.

And it worked, at least for me.

So, if you encounter this error, try to use the Powershell :)

Comment: still old, and still works today :) thanks!

Comment: I have five .exe compiled by me using g++ on windows. They all run fine in "git bash" shell. I was getting "Entry Point Not Found" error when I executed them from windows "cmd" shell. Using Powershell got me two of them working and 3 stopped giving run time error!

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me because an old zlib1.dll was being loaded from somewhere in my PATH. I copied a new version to system32 and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth looking at this page:

http://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#start-a-kivy-application

Comment: Sorry I even posted this problem in kivy IRC. This is not a problem which is relevant to Kivy. I guess this is my system problem. Kivy 1.8.0 is runnin on my system without any hassle.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Finally I solve it with running command with administrator privilege (when the command === python -m pip install kivy.deps.gstreamer --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/packages/simple/).